# How to check if two arraylist are the same (Unit test with JUnit)

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

Before you mark my question as duplicate, i have tried solutions in other post but didnt work. This what i have

```
Clientes Cliente1 = new Clientes(1,PinturasCliente1,ColoresCliente1);
Clientes Cli= new Clientes(1,PinturasCliente1,ColoresCliente1);
ArrayList<Clientes> ListaClientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
ArrayList<Clientes> ClientesMetodo =  new ArrayList<Clientes>();
ListaClientes.add(Cliente1);
ClientesMetodo.add(Cli);

Assert.assertEquals(ListaClientes, ClientesMetodo);
```

This return error, and by the way `PinturasCliente1` and `ColoresCliente1` are `ArrayList` too.

So, how can I test both `ListaClientes` and `ClientesMetodo` have not the same Objects, but the Objectes they have added, have the same information.

Comment: By properly overriding the `equals` method in  your `Clientes` class.

Comment: Here's [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner

Comment: Go ahead, search questions here on SO about the equals method, read articles on the internet. Basically, the equals method tells whether 2 instances are *semantically* equal, i.e. the equals method should return true if two different instances of the class `Person` have the same name, the same lastname, the same date and place of birth and the same id/social security number, or maybe it's enough to return true if they have the same id number only. I mean, if they actually represent the same person.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the equals method on the classes of the objects you are adding to your list.

from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> public boolean equals(Object obj)
>
> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>
> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns
>     true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then
>     x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or
>     consistently return false, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
>
> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.
>
> Parameters:
>       obj - the reference object with which to compare. Returns:
>       true if this object is the same as the obj argument; false otherwise.

note: If you override the equals method in a given class its also recommended to overwrite the hashCode method.

Answer (score 0):

AbstractList.equals() is defined:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

so it use **o1.equals(o2)** to compare each element. In your case, it's Clientes. But Clientes.equals() by default is Object.equals(), it's defined:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Apparently, Cliente1 != Cli.
So you should override Object.equlas() in Clientes. You can check this by add

```
public boolean equals(Object o) { return true; }
```

in Clientes. Then focus on the implementation. And for PinturasCliente1 and ColoresCliente1, you'd better also implement own equals() for each of the class in case of they are not the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method that's all objects gets from `Object`,

If you using `maven / gradle` you can import [`Lombok project`](https://projectlombok.org/features/all)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.20.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And use it to generate `equals` and `hashcode` methods auto.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Clientes {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement equals() and hashCode() methods and use the equals() methods from AbstractList your program will work if only both lists contains the same elements in the same order.
If both lists contain the same elements but in different order, then it would return false even if the two lists are same in content. I do not know whether it is your requirement, but if that is, then you'll need to write your own logic to compare the lists.